# Electric current doubt

Tags: electric-current

How to find out the direction in which the magnetic needle of a magnetic compass aligns itself when kept beside a current carrying conductor?

Comment: Google Right Hand Thumb Rule to find the direction of magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

A magnetic needle is a magnetic dipole. Assuming you are familiar with the fact that when magnetic dipoles are placed in a magnetic field the experience a torque which rotates it such that it achieves the position of stable equilibrium ( a position in which the potential energy is at it's minimum ) so say we have a magnetic dipole $ M $ inclined to a magnetic field $ B $  at an angle of say $ \theta $ radian with it then a torque acts on the dipole so as to rotate it in such a manner that it is aligned with magnetic field at that point in the space where it is kept [image] also just for additional information the torque is given by the expression $ \tau = M × B $